# Typeorm – How do you use the TS `Relation` type for one-to-many relations?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

On the [Typeorm FAQs page](https://typeorm.io/faq#how-to-use-typeorm-in-esm-projects), the docs give instructions to wrap entities in a `Relation` type to prevent circular dependencies, but the example they give is with a one-to-one relationship. This leaves the solution for a many-to-one or one-to-many rather ambiguous. Which of the following would be the correct implementation?

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
    @OneToMany(() => Profile, (profile) => profile.user)
    profiles: Relation<Profile[]>;
}
```

or

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
    @OneToMany(() => Profile, (profile) => profile.user)
    profiles: Relation<Profile>[];
}
```

Or, does it even matter which way you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the right form as you already provided:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
    @OneToMany(() => Profile, (profile) => profile.users)
    profiles: Relation<Profile[]>;
}
```